# Matching two values in a table to another value in a table sql

Tags: sql-server

I was hoping someone could help me with the proper way to do this. I have a table called delivered where I have member and friend_member id. These values both map to memberid in the member table. In the member table I need to find if these two memberid (member and friend_member) have the same shipping method which is called ship_method and zip code which is called zip_code in the member table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join both columns of `delivered` to the `members` table and compare the other columns there:

```
SELECT m.name, f.name
FROM   delivered d
JOIN   members m ON d.member_id = m.id
JOIN   members f ON d.friend_membner_id = f.id
WHERE  m.shipping_method = f.shipping_method AND
       m.zip_code = f.zip_code
```